# Mysql join query improvement and GROUP_CONCAT on GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have two tables which I need to perform a left outer join on to get the result set I want. The query I have now works but its taking too long to process. Any suggestions?

Query:

```
SELECT Date_format(a.call_date, '%Y-%m-%d') Call_Date,
   Date_format(a.call_date, '%H:%i:%s') Call_Time,
   a.lead_id,
   customer_number,
   status,
   a.call_type,
   agent,
   skill,
   campaign,
   disposition,
   hangup,
   a.uniqueid,
   time_to_answer,
   talk_time,
   hold_sec,
   wrapup_sec,
   Date_format(start_time, '%H:%i:%s')  Start_Time,
   Date_format(end_time, '%H:%i:%s')    End_Time,
   Ifnull(a.transfered, b.transfered)   AS transfer,
   comments,
   location,
   duration,
   handling_time,
   number_dialed                        AS DID
FROM   cdr_temp a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT USER,
                           Substring(number_dialed, 18, 11) AS transfered,
                           uniqueid
                    FROM   transfertable)
                   b
                ON a.uniqueid = b.uniqueid
WHERE  a.call_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-23 00:00:00'
GROUP  BY a.lead_id,
      b.uniqueid
```

Tables:

- cdr_temp

[image: cdr_temp]

- transfertable

[image: transfertable]

Index:

```
uniqueid and call_date for transfertable
uniqueid and lead_id for cdr_temp
```

Explain on query

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1333    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  transfertable   ref     uniqueid    uniqueid    22  test.a.uniqueid     1
```

PS: I need to concatenate skills and number_dialed on GROUP BY. I've tried using GROUP_CONCAT but it didn't work and I have no idea why.

UPDATE: I've tried this query using a temp table. Is it better?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE transfertable_temp (
    INDEX idx (uniqueid, transfered)
)
SELECT uniqueid, SUBSTRING(number_dialed, 18, 11) AS transfered
FROM transfertable WHERE call_date BETWEEN '2019-03-25 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-25 23:59:59';
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(a.call_date, '%Y-%m-%d') Call_Date,
    DATE_FORMAT(a.call_date, '%H:%i:%s') Call_Time,
    a.lead_id,
    customer_number,
    status,
    a.call_type,
    agent,
    GROUP_CONCAT(skill SEPARATOR ';') AS Skill,
    campaign,
    disposition,
    hangup,
    a.uniqueid,
    time_to_answer,
    talk_time,
    hold_sec,
    wrapup_sec,
    Date_format(start_time, '%H:%i:%s') Start_Time,
    Date_format(end_time, '%H:%i:%s') End_Time,
    IFNULL(a.transfered, b.transfered) transfer,
    comments,
    location,
    duration,
    handling_time,
    number_dialed AS DID
 FROM cdr_temp a
 LEFT JOIN transfertable_temp b
    ON a.uniqueid = b.uniqueid
 WHERE a.call_date BETWEEN '2019-03-25 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-25 23:59:59'
 GROUP BY a.lead_id,
            b.uniqueid
```

Comment: I do not see GROUP_CONCAT in your query. Try to simplify the query (remove all fields except those which are used in JOIN/WHERE/GROUP BY/AGGREGATE/PRIMARY KEYS).

Comment: I've edited the query and added the GROUP_CONCAT, please check above

Comment: What table the argument `skill` is taken from? `transfertable_temp`?

Comment: its taken from cdr_temp but it is there in transfertable table also

Comment: If it is taken from `cdr_temp` where `uniqueid` is unique, than all values of `cdr_temp.skill` which are GROUP_CONCATed are the same...

Comment: i thought so too, but it always return as null when using group by but it returns the correct value if i remove the group by

Comment: *its taken from cdr_temp but it is there in transfertable table also* I'm generally surprised you don't get an error message *Column 'skill' in field list is ambiguous*...

Comment: this query was not written by me but i think there's no error because he has used the alias such as a.skill or b.skill in the first query and in the updated query which i edited, its because i've used a temporary table

Comment: Anycase if query source contains more than one table (ever when 2 copies of the same table) the best practice is to specify table alias for each field in a query.

Comment: That's true, the answer you provided before you removed it gave the exact same result as my query but faster. Thanks, though not completely fixed the query is now much faster

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should avoid `JOIN ( SELECT ... )`.  In the past it was notoriously inefficient.  In later versions it is sometimes somewhat slower than alternatives.

Instead, let's get rid of the `JOIN` some of the time:

```
...
    Ifnull(a.transfered, b.transfered)   AS transfer,
    ...
FROM   cdr_temp a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT USER,
                           Substring(number_dialed, 18, 11) AS transfered,
                           uniqueid
                    FROM   transfertable)
                   b
                ON a.uniqueid = b.uniqueid
WHERE  ...
GROUP  BY a.lead_id,
          b.uniqueid
```

-->

```
...
    Ifnull(a.transfered, 
             ( SELECT substring... FROM transfertable
                          WHERE uniqueid = a.uniqueid
             )
          )   AS transfer,
    ...
FROM   cdr_temp a
   -- gone:  LEFT OUTER JOIN
WHERE  ...
GROUP  BY a.lead_id,
          a.uniqueid  -- Note "a."
```

It is "improper" to `GROUP BY` only some of the non-aggregate columns; you will get random values for the others.  Is a "skill" associated with a "lead"?

It would be more informative to have `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  What are the `PRIMARY KEYs` of the tables?  Are there any other `UNIQUE` columns?

Comment: I've cross-checked and yes GROUP BY should not be there to get the whole information.

Comment: @on3ss - Read about only_full_group_by